# Setting AllowPrivilegeEscalation:false

Tags: kubernetes

I want to set AllowPrivilegeEscalation to false in a nonprivileged container but running with CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability. As per docs "AllowPrivilegeEscalation is true always when the container is: 1) run as Privileged OR 2) has CAP_SYS_ADMIN." . In this case it will be set to true or false ?

Answer (score 3):

As you already found in [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/):

> `AllowPrivilegeEscalation`: Controls whether a process can gain more
> privileges than its parent process. This bool directly controls
> whether the `no_new_privs` flag gets set on the container process.
> **`AllowPrivilegeEscalation` is true always when the container is: 1) run as Privileged OR 2) has `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.**

In your case the container has `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` so it would have the `AllowPrivilegeEscalation` set to `true`.

This behavior is also explained in more detail in the [AllowPrivilegeEscalation design document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/auth/no-new-privs.md).

Comment: @sacboy Does my answer help you with your use case?